# 5 Pin button to tell Continuous Servo to run for certain amount of time

Tags: arduino-uno, button, code-review, wires

I'm working with a 5 pin dome button, trying to get that to tell the motor to spin for a certain amount of time when it is pressed then stop until it is pressed again, where it would then run for the same amount of time. It's my first time doing anything with arduinos, wiring and coding. I have gotten the button to light up but I have no clue how to have it make the servo motor run once it's pressed. Can anyone advise on how to wire all of this up, along with some advice on the code? It's a school project, would be extremely helpful since my professor doesn't really have any interest in helping here. Thanks!

Using a red dome button (5 pin from Sparkfun.com), Arduino R3, continuous servo motor, and a mini breadboard

Comment: Hi, your question is currently not very specific. Have you searched the web foe something like "arduino read button tutorial" or "arduino servo tutorial" to learn how each part of your project can work individually? If yes, please explain where exactly you had problems understanding which tutorial. Also: please also provide a link to the buttons sparkfun product page, so that we can be sure we are talking about the same product

Comment: the button does not control the servo, the Arduino controls the servo ... the button only tells the Arduino that you pressed it ... it is the program that resoonds to the button press in some desired way